# Odd behaviour with hibernate JSON converter

Tags: java, json, hibernate

I am having some trouble with converting a Set of POJO's to a JSON string so I can store it in a database column. The conversion to JSON works as expected but when the conversion from JSON to a Set< Qualification > happens it always returns a `LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap>` which is causing issues.

The weird thing is that inside my converter the JSON string is converted successfully to a `Set<Qualification>`. When I debug in my IDE and step through the execution I can see that after it calls a `deepCopy` method in the `MutableMutabilityPlan` abstract class. At this point the data is of type `LinkedHashSet<LinkedHashMap>` and not `Set<Qualification>` from the conversion.

Here is my converter.

```
public class SetToStringConverter implements AttributeConverter<Set<Qualification>, String> {

private final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
private final String errorMessage = "converter.invalid";

@Override
public String convertToDatabaseColumn(final Set<Qualification> items) {
    try {
        return mapper.writeValueAsString(items);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        throw new ConverterFailureException(errorMessage);
    }
}

@Override
public Set<Qualification> convertToEntityAttribute(final String data) {
    try {
        if (data != null) {
            final Set<Qualification> s = mapper.readValue(data, new TypeReference<Set<Qualification>>() {});
            return s; // Debugging here I have the correct type
        }

        return new HashSet<>();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new ConverterFailureException(errorMessage);
    }
}
```

}

I have done some research and have tried various approaches but the result is always the same.

Has anyone run into this issue before or can see anything wrong with my converter. Let me know if anything isn't clear so I can provide more information.

Thanks very much for the help.

Comment: Set is an interface. LinkedHashSet is an implementation of the Set interface. What exactly do you expect instead of LinkedHashSet, why, and what's the problem with the value being a LinkedHashSet?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I would expect to get a Set<Qualification> and not a Set<LinkedHashMap>. My description wasn't clear. I'll update it.

Comment: I don't think we can do anything to help you based on the code you provided. The problem is elsewhere.